# Debugging GLFW application with GLFW_CURSOR_DISABLED

Tags: c++, glfw

On my up-to-date Archlinux system I am developing an OpenGL application in C++ and I am using GLFW for the window creation.
For different reasons I would like to disable the cursor with

```
glfwSetInputMode(window, GLFW_CURSOR, GLFW_CURSOR_DISABLED);
```

This disables the mouse, makes the "mouse_move_delta" computation easy, etc.
My problem is that it makes debugging almost impossible, because when the execution is paused, my cursor is still "lost".

I tried to use the glfwSetWindowFocusCallback() function to "enable" the mouse when focus is lost, but when a breakpoint is hit, this callback is not called.

```
   glfwSetWindowFocusCallback(m_window, [](GLFWwindow* window, int isInFocus)
   {
      if (isInFocus == GLFW_FALSE)
      {
         std::cout << "NOT in focus" << std::endl;
         glfwSetInputMode(window, GLFW_CURSOR, GLFW_CURSOR_NORMAL);
      }
      else
      {
         glfwSetInputMode(window, GLFW_CURSOR, GLFW_CURSOR_DISABLED);
      }
   });
```

I didn't find too much similar questions to mine, one was this:
https://github.com/glfw/glfw/issues/530
This says it is not possible to use glfwSetWindowFocusCallback for a case like this. The link proposes a solution, but I don't understand that and I don't think the solution would be to recompile the GLFW...

Now what I do when I would like to debug is to set the cursor to normal (GLFW_CURSOR_NORMAL) recompile and rerun my application, I just don't want to believe this is the way it should be done.

So my question is: is it possible to debug (with enabled mouse cursor etc) when GLFW_CURSOR_DISABLED is used?

UPDATED:
As it figured out the issue was the LXDE (or the window manager it uses). I switched to XFCE and now everything works as expected.

Comment: An alternative might be to wrap the `glfwSetInputMode(window, GLFW_CURSOR, GLFW_CURSOR_DISABLED);` into an `#ifndef _DEBUG` and `#endif`. Thus, it would become effective in a non-debug build only.

Comment: @Scheff'sCat Thank you for the idea. Unfortunately the difference between GLFW_CURSOR_DISABLED and GLFW_CURSOR_NORMAL is not just that the  cursor is disabled or not, but also in DISABLED mode it is not possible the move the cursor over the boundaries of the window, instead the cursor is "captured". While in NORMAL mode the cursor can leave the window. It would be fine to run and debug the same code with the same behavior.

Comment: I see your point. However, a captured cursor is fine as long as the application does what it is supposed to. Otherwise, (if the application has an unexpected bug) such a grabbed cursor can cause serious head-ache. I stumbled into such issues some years ago and recorded a grabbed cursor as one of my "never-do"s... ;-)

Comment: Did you consider remote debugging?

Comment: As it figured out the issue was the LXDE (or the window manager it uses). I switched to XFCE and now everything works as expected.